# JBPM: Add MySQL connector dependency to kie workbench [ver 6.2]

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jboss, jbpm

I'm trying to add mysql connector dependency to kie workbench. I added it by uploading the jar to the artifact repository and adding the dependency by going to project settings. When the service task that uses the connector executes, it's not able to load the mysql's Driver class. Here's more detail on how I'm using the service task - [Service task using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32232010/jbpm-how-to-run-a-sql-query-from-a-service-taskver-6-2)

When the service task execute I get this message on the workbench - `Unexpected error encountered : [com.sample.bpmn.hello:36 - GetData:3] -- Unable to build entity manager factory`

When I look at wildfly's server.log, it seems the jar didn't get added properly - `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

When I add the dependency on the workbench, I see the following warnings. I'm not able to figure out what they mean -
`Verification of class com.mysql.jdbc.integration.c3p0.MysqlConnectionTester failed and will not be available for authoring. Please check the necessary external dependencies for this project are configured correctly.`

`Verification of class com.mysql.jdbc.integration.jboss.ExtendedMysqlExceptionSorter failed and will not be available for authoring. Please check the necessary external dependencies for this project are configured correctly.`

`Verification of class com.mysql.jdbc.integration.jboss.MysqlValidConnectionChecker failed and will not be available for authoring. Please check the necessary external dependencies for this project are configured correctly.`

Please let me know if more info is needed.
Much appreciated.

[PS] - I must say that I just got started with hibernate as well with no prior experience. So it could be a basic thing I'm missing there.

Comment: How did you setup your enivironment. Did you use the demo install scripts or did you manually set it up?

Comment: The environment was setup by someone else using docker. The workbench itself is actually running off of mysql instead of h2. I added my persistence unit to the same persistence.xml(under jbpm console war). The difference is 'transaction type' for PU used for jbpm is `JTA` while I'm using `RESOURCE_LOCAL`. The one using JTA has data source defined in a separate file while I'm defining the source as properties -

Comment: `<properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://172.xx.0.1:3306/MyDB"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="auser"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="apassword"/>
              <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>`